# python exec command works in console but not in program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is that running exec() on a variable with the name of a named argument does not work in normal operation of the program, but setting a break point and executing the line of code in question at the same location seems to work.

Reproduction of the issue follows:

```py
"""

    LEGACY CODE, CANNOT CHANGE
    vvvvvvvvvvv

"""

from collections import namedtuple


class A_Object(namedtuple('A_object', 'parameter_a' ' parameter_b')):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        init = super(A_Object, cls).__new__(cls, parameter_a=[], parameter_b=[])
        return init

    """
    
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
        LEGACY CODE, CANNOT CHANGE
    
    """

    def _remove_all_data(self):
        for field in self._fields:
            print("removing field:", field)

            # This does not work in the normal execution of the program,
            # but if you set a break point and execute the same command in the python console ( in Pycharm ) it works.
            exec('self = self._replace({0}=[])'.format(field))

        return self


def driver():
    a = A_Object()

    a.parameter_a.append('a')
    a.parameter_a.append('b')
    a.parameter_a.append('c')

    a.parameter_b.append(1)
    a.parameter_b.append(2)
    a.parameter_b.append(3)

    # Try to remove all data from properties.
    a = a._remove_all_data()

    tmp = a._asdict()

    for k in tmp.keys():
        for i in range(0, len(tmp[k])):
            print('{}[{}]='.format(k,i), tmp[k][i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver()
```

This minimum reproducible example will show that running the program will output the contents of parameter_a, and parameter_b ( That is the issue ). The desired outcome would be parameter_a, and parameter_b to be empty list. If you put a break point on the `exec('self = self._replace({0}=[])'.format(field))` line and during debug open up the python console in pycharm and run that line of code "`exec('self = self._replace({0}=[])'.format(field))`" in the console. it will clear the parameter_a, and paramter_b ( giving the desired output ).

Comment: you cannot modify local variables with `exec`/`eval`. You shouldn't be using `exec` here in the first place

Comment: But clearly that is not exactly the case if I can use exec to modify local variables in the python console. And I agree NOT using exec/eval in this case is best practice.

Comment: No, you cannot, in Python 3. A debugger console is different from a normal environment (it's actually using `exec` already...)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `exec` for this: if you want a dynamically-named keyword argument, use the `**kwargs` syntax. You might as well also replace all the fields at once instead of calling `_replace` multiple times in a loop:

```py
def _remove_all_data(self):
    return self._replace(**{ f: [] for f in self._fields })
```

Comment: I forgot the `**` when I first tired `kwargs` pass in. This solved for the desire output/outcome. Thank you. Before I mark this as the answer do you know why exec has that odd behavior of not working in this program?

Comment: @Theisen did you read the [documentation for exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)?  it warns you that modifications to local variables will not work.

Comment: It's not odd behaviour - it's the expected behaviour. `exec` doesn't change the values of local variables like `self`. As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for the `exec` function advise: *"Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns."*